# Array row not incrementing inside loop in R

Tags: arrays, r, loops

I've searched but I can't seem to find either the problem or a solution to the symptoms here. I have a nested loop in R, looping first through row entries of an array, then column entries.
When a condition is met - the value is meant to be written to another array, with location specified by the row and column loop values.

The problem is that the row does not appear to increment, and only the first row of my "answer" array is populated.

Code follows:

```
nblocks<-nrow(Data_3m)

Data_MnQ50_3m<-array(rep(NA,(nrow(Topvar_3m)*100*4)),c(nrow(Topvar_3m),100,4))

loopcount<-1

for(r in 1:nblocks){

for (sim in 1:100){

    if((Data_3m[r,sim,1]>= Mn3O4_Q50[r])&(loopcount<51)){

        Data_MnQ50_3m[r,loopcount,1]<-Data_3m[r,sim,1]
        Data_MnQ50_3m[r,loopcount,2]<-Data_3m[r,sim,2]
        Data_MnQ50_3m[r,loopcount,3]<-Data_3m[r,sim,3]
        Data_MnQ50_3m[r,loopcount,4]<-Data_3m[r,sim,4]
        loopcount<-loopcount + 1
        }   
    else{}
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simply use `sim` as your counter. Also, `loopcount` is in the `if` loop, so it might not always change.

Comment: @Marcinthebox I don't think so -- it appears the OP wants a "smaller" output matrix, so the 2nd index only increments when written to.  Matt: am I correct?  Are you calling the first index ( `r` value) the output "row" ?

Comment: BTW,  use `R`'s vectorization:   `bar[a,b,1:4] <- foo[a,d,1:4]` instead of four separate lines.

Comment: Can you include some of your data?

Comment: @Carl - you are correct. The basics of what I am doing here is stripping out of all 4 "slices" of the array, conditional on values in the first "slice" meeting meeting specific criteria. Loopcount should only increment when the criteria are met. To be more specific, I am collecting the values of all 4 "slices" of the tensor that are conditional to the 50th percentile of the first "slice", so of the 100 original columns of each "slice", only 50 are retained.

Comment: I should add, the loopcount is not the problem. For some reason, r (which does indeed reference the "row" of the array / tensor) is not incrementing in the taget array. Only the first row is being populated accross all "slices", and for the life of me I can't see why.

Comment: UPDATE: Solved guys. The problem was that I was not resetting loopcount for the next row of calculations (next r loop). Too much swapping between R and VB for me! Loop requirements getting confused! Thanks to those who replied.